# Can I install Confluent on HDP 2.4 platform

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, confluent-platform, hortonworks-data-platform

I'm trying to install Confluent over HDP for Kafka Streams which think may not be possible could you people suggest me what to do

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to install Confluent Platform using Ambari.  If that's the case then you want to use a [custom service install](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AMBARI/Defining+a+Custom+Stack+and+Services#DefiningaCustomStackandServices-Example:ImplementingaCustomService) or you will need to wait for HDP to support Kafka 0.10 which includes Kafka Streams.  The alternative route is to install Confluent Platform in parallel with HDP and just not activate the Kafka version that ships with HDP.  This will require that you monitor and manage the Confluent Platform independently.

Answer (score 0):

> for Kafka Streams

Kafka Streams is a client library that can use with any Kafka cluster above version 0.10. You do not specifically require "Confluent Platform"

That being said, if the version that HDP/Cloudera provide of Kafka is not useful for you, then you should provision external infrastructure for it.